# Vagrant - Provisioning multitple VBox-VMs with pre-defined names

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have a bit of trouble provisioning a multi-machine setup from a Vagrantfile.

```
VM_NAME="node"
IMAGE_NAME="centos/7"

Nodes=3
NodeMEM=4096
NodeCPU=2
NodeGUI=false


(1..Nodes).each do |i|
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    v_hostname=VM_NAME+"-#{i}"
    config.vm.define "node-#{i}" do |node|
      node.vm.box = IMAGE_NAME
      config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vbox|
        vbox.memory = NodeMEM
        vbox.cpus   = NodeCPU
        vbox.gui    = NodeGUI
        vbox.name   = v_hostname
      end

      node.vm.hostname=v_hostname
    end
  end
end
```

**My expectation:** the hostname inside the VM (node.vm.hostname) and the VBox machine name are set to identical values: node-1, node-2, node-3

**Actual Result:** (removed some lines from network settings, guest additions and rsyncing folders)

```
#> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'node-1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'node-2' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'node-3' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> node-1: Importing base box 'centos/7'...
==> node-1: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> node-1: Checking if box 'centos/7' version '2004.01' is up to date...
==> node-1: Setting the name of the VM: node-3
==> node-1: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[...]
==> node-1: Setting hostname...
[...]
==> node-2: Importing base box 'centos/7'...
==> node-2: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> node-2: Checking if box 'centos/7' version '2004.01' is up to date...
A VirtualBox machine with the name 'node-3' already exists.
Please use another name or delete the machine with the existing
name, and try again.
```

The hostname inside the VM is correctly set to "node-1" and the node name used by Vagrant as well. It's only the VBox machine name which is not set correctly.

I already tried using different orders (loop inside-out, VBox at the end), removing dashes from the hostname, setting the variables identical to v_hostname but explicitly for vbox_name.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong here?

---

Additional information

I added another step to create and mount a secondary disk.

```
vbox.customize ["createmedium", "disk", "--filename", "/mnt/sdb/VirtualBox/disks/"+v_hostname+"-ceph.vdi", "--size", "10240"]
```

While the first node was still being provisioned I could see all three disks (one for each node) have alreay been created and the disk of the third node was attached to the first node.

I also tried add "--no-parallel" to "vagrant up" but no luck.
I'm not sure why the "vbox.customize" steps are run for all iterations already in the first loop but I think this is the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vbox|
```

must be changed to

```
node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vbox|
```

```
(1..Nodes).each do |i|
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    v_hostname=VM_NAME+"-#{i}"
    config.vm.define v_hostname do |node|
      node.vm.box = IMAGE_NAME
      node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vbox|
        vbox.memory = NodeMEM
        vbox.cpus   = NodeCPU
        vbox.gui    = NodeGUI
        vbox.name   = v_hostname
      end

      node.vm.hostname=v_hostname
    end
  end
end
```